# Parallel evaluation with hyperopt using mongdb is not working

Tags: python, mongodb

I am newbie with mongodb and I wanted to use it for parallel evaluations in [hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin). So far I have followed the following step:

1. Install `MongoDB 3.7.3` at `C:/Mongodb`
2. Create an empty database folder as `C:/Mongodb/test_trial`
3. Start a `mongod process` in command prompt typing the following:

`"C:\Mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath "C:\Mongodb\test_trial" --port 1234`

Doing so, I get this output:

> 2018-04-04T13:35:18.543+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for 
>   connections on port 1234

4. Then, I test the following python script in spyder which uses hyperopt on mongodb:

```py
import math
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp
from hyperopt.mongoexp import MongoTrials

trials = MongoTrials('mongo://localhost:1234/test_trial/jobs', exp_key='exp1')
best = fmin(math.sin, hp.uniform('x', -2, 2), trials=trials, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=10)
```

When running the script, nothing seems to happen on the ipython console and I get this message:

> no last_id found, re-trying

I then create a new folder called `C:/Mongodb/test_trial/jobs` and rerun the previous script. Again nothing seems to happen and I get this message on the iPython console:

> over-writing old domain trials attachment

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to have started a starting a *hyperopt-mongo-worker* to listen and respond to your requests as given in https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/Parallelizing-Evaluations-During-Search-via-MongoDB

```
hyperopt-mongo-worker --mongo=localhost:1234/test_trial --poll-interval=0.1
```

Hope this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`hyperopt-mongo-worker` file is not fully optimized for usage on a Windows environment. It is not possible to run  hyperopt with MongoDB.